# How to design generic backward compatible API for embedded software application library interface in C?

Tags: c, interface, embedded

I am tasked to assist with the design of a dynamic library (exposed with a C interface) aimed to be used in embed software application on various embed platform (Android,Windows,Linux).

Main requirements are speed , and decoupling.
For the decoupling part : one of our requirement is to be able to facilitate integration and so permit backward compatibility and resilience.

My library have some entry points that should be called by the integrating software (like an initialize constructor to provide options as where to log, how to behave etc...) and could also call some callback in the application (an event to inform when task is finished).

So I have come with several propositions but as each of one not seems great I am searching advice on a better or standard ways to achieve decoupling an d backward compatibility than this 3 ways that I have come up :

- First an option that I could think of is to have a generic interface call for my exposed entry points for example with a hashmap of key/values for the parameters of my functions so in pseudo code it gives something like  :

  myLib.Initialize(Key_Value_Option_Array_Here);
- Another option is to provide a generic function to provide all the options to the library :

  myLib.SetOption(Key_Of_Option, Value_OfOption);
   myLib.SetCallBack(Key_Of_Callbak, FunctionPointer);
- When presenting my option my collegue asked me why not use a google protobuf argument as interface between the library and the embed software : but it seems weird to me, as their will be a performance hit on each call for serialization and deserialization.

  Are there any more efficient or standard way that you coud think of?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a struct for optional arguments:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t optArg1;
    float optArg2;
} MyLib_InitOptArgs_T;


void MyLib_Init(int16_t arg1, uint32_t arg2, MyLib_InitOptArgs_T const * optionalArgs);
```

Then you could use compound literals on function call:

```
MyLib_Init(1, 2, &(MyLib_InitOptArgs_T){ .optArg2=1.2f });
```

All non-specified values would have zero-ish value (0, NULL, NaN), and would be considered unused. Similarly, when passing NULL for struct pointer, all optional arguments would be considered unused.

Downside with this method is that if you expect to have many new arguments in the future, structure could grow too big. But whether that is an issue, depends on what your limits are.

---

Another option is to simply have multiple smaller initialization functions for initializating different subsystems. This could be combined with the optional arguments system above.

Comment: The compound literal could respond to my problem. If I have callback to be defined I could also add them to the argument structure. By the way, what do you think about the protobuf structured message alternative?

Comment: @Dypso My first reaction is that it is overkill, and I would first consider something like hashmap instead. But I don't know your enough of your case to give definitive answer; maybe protobuf is exactly what you need. Personally I would be more conservative, because further you go from the language, more you start losing helpful things like type safety and other compile time checks.